What is the name for the time duration format like "8h 3m 4s" (as opposed to 08:03:04)?
Usually you see time durations listed using colons, like "08:03".
However that's also often ambiguous -- is that 8 hours and 3 minutes, or 8 minutes and 3 seconds? It also doesn't extend cleanly upwards to includes things like days.
So I occasionally come across the alternative format that uses a lowercase unit symbol and a space -- "8h 3m" or "8m 3s" which has no ambiguity, and easily extends to include things like days: "12d 8h 3m".
I'm just wondering -- is there a name for this format? If I wanted to provide it as a formatting preference in an application to end users, what name would I give it? And for that matter, what name do you give the standard "08:03" format that contrasts with it?
At first I thought perhaps "colon time" and "HMS" time, but it seems like HMS time usually refers to "HHMMSS" or "HH:MM:SS" times like "080312" or "08:03:12", and doesn't actually use the "h m s" symbols at all. And "colon time" doesn't seem to be a common phrase either.
I've gone through Google results and scoured Wikipedia and I can't find any actual name for a time duration format like "8h 3m 4s", that uses explicit unit symbols. Or, for that matter, any actual name for "colon time" because it's just, well, time.
Can anyone help? How do we unambiguously refer to these two paradigms for writing out time durations, so that we can intelligently talk about them?
(To be clear, this question is not about how to format time durations in computer code. It's easy to do that with formatting strings. This question is about what to call these two types of common, yet contrasting, time duration formats -- so that we can talk about what we're trying to achieve with the computer code.)
